# Return index value of each row in MySQL

Tags: mysql, indexing, limit, increment

I would like to know if there is a way to return the current index of each row in a MySQL query, for example:

```
SELECT current_index, name FROM table LIMIT 10,10
```

So that the resulting rows would have

```
10, 'somename',
11, 'somename',
etc....
```

It would be a value based on the starting limit value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SET @rn = 10;

SELECT  @rn := @rn + 1 AS current_index,
        name
FROM    mytable
LIMIT   10, 10
```

Please note that `LIMIT 10, 10` means entries `11` to `20`.

Also note that `LIMIT` without a stable `ORDER BY` is not guaranteed to persist from query to query (and does not persist in some engines).

Comment: Is this meaningful without `ORDER BY`?

Comment: @eggyal: given the current implementation details, yes (it will always be an index scan on the shortest index containing `name`, or a table/`PRIMARY` scan should such an index not exist or be larger than the table). But you're right, this should not be relied upon.